How can I tell if gas pipes are in need of replacement?
A plumber came today to inspect and drain my water heater, normal maintenance. While here he told me that the gas line to the water heater and the valve on the water heater are leaking and need to be replaced.
I'm not a professional but when looking at the steel pipes I don't see any visible signs of damage or corrosion. When doing the water and soap test at the joints there are no bubbles, the valve is old but also not visibly damaged, and there are no hissing sounds or smell of gas. He also did not recommend that I turn the gas off or call the city for an inspection/safety check.
Am I being scammed? I don't want to not replace the pipes if there really is a leak but I can't find one and he didn't show me any either.

Nothing you've reported points to a problem, but it's possible there's something you aren't seeing. My first step would be calling the plumber to ask for clarification. If he's honest, he won't mind a bit. Then we'll have more to talk about.

Possible the shut off valve is what is leaking when closed.  The valve is not closing completely.

put some soap water on the pipe connections to see if it makes bubbles

no plumber would leave a gas pipe leaking. If he didn't turn the gas off and leave it off he's scamming you.

At least, no gas fitter would leave The gas pipe leaking. There are plumbers who are clueless about gas and shouldn't be allowed anywhere near it.

Just to emphasize: scammer. Get a second opinion. (There might be something real going on with the tpr valve, but a “plumber” who leaves a “leaky” gas system on doesn’t get a second chance.) If it turns out completely false, review sites help others in your area.

Do not know if true/real, but just watched a youtube short.  A woman smelled gas, two different plumbers and two trips from a gas fitter said no leaks.  This guy comes and thinks the same thing.  Checks something and finds leak in a valve going into return(unknown what his meaning).  Ask the your plumber where he thinks your leak is.

Sounds like the jury's out on the plumber, but you can just test it yourself for under $30. I can perform a pretty good leak test using an electronic gas detector (like this).  I find it particularly helpful when inspecting an installation with multiple joints that are not visible or easily accessible where they can be tested with liquid leak detectors.  Moving the wand around the area tells me if there's a leak anywhere in the vicinity.  If there is, I can chase it down with the wand and confirm with a bubble test.
